# C# - Difference in ASP.NET of buffered(MVC) and non-buffered(WEB API)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

As the title stated, so what is the difference in performance and usage of each one?
And also what is the reason of being buffered and non-buffered? Memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some differences between MVC and WebAPI’s parameter binding:

MVC only had model binders and no formatters. That’s because MVC would model bind over the request’s body (which it commonly expected to just be FormUrl encoded), whereas WebAPI uses a serializer over the request’s body.

MVC buffered the request body, and so could easily feed it into model binding. WebAPI does not buffer the request body, and so does not model bind against the request body by default.

WebAPI’s binding can be determined entirely statically based off the action signature types. For example, in WebAPI, you know statically whether a parameter will bind against the body or the query string. Whereas in MVC, the model binding system would search both body and query string.

Go through this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: Is there a performance issue being a buffered and non-buffered?